# Реакция на повторное нажатие (повторный выбор) элемента Spinner, когда он уже выбран

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner, android-interface

Использую стандартный Spinner (Android Studio, Kotlin, android.widget). Нужна реакция на повторное нажатие элемента Spinner, после того как этот элемент уже был выбран. Я не нашёл стандартных способов как это сделать. Вот мой код:

binding.alarmRepeatingModeSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

```
        // Вызывается при выборе любого элемента Spinner (кроме уже выбранного)
        override fun onItemSelected(
            parentView: AdapterView<*>?,
            selectedItemView: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            val selectedValue = parentView?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
            if(selectedValue != "Select days") {
                hideWeekDaysAbbreviatedText()
            }
            else {
                //Реакция на нажатие на элемент "Select days".
                //Если значение спиннера уже установлено на "Select days", то повторное нажатие ничего не делает.
                //А мне нужно, чтобы срабатывало. Помогите!
                showWeekDaysChoosingPopup()
            }
        }

        //Вызывается если ничего не выбрано (не используется)
        override fun onNothingSelected(parentView: AdapterView<*>?) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На англоязычном StackOverflow уже отвечали на этот вопрос 3 года назад:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64550613/spinner-already-selected-item-selection-event

Думаю, что стандартного решения нет. Но вот как оно делается (у меня всё заработало):

1. Создаём класс расширяющий `Spinner`

```
    class MySpinner(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner(
    context,
    attrs
)
{
    var listener: OnItemSelectedListener? = null

    override fun setSelection(position: Int)
    {
        super.setSelection(position)
        if (position == selectedItemPosition)
        {
            listener!!.onItemSelected(this, selectedView, position, selectedItemId)
        }
    }

    override fun setOnItemSelectedListener(listener: OnItemSelectedListener?)
    {
        this.listener = listener
    }
}
```

2. Добавляем ссылку на него в Layout (заменяем спиннер на свой). Вместо `com.example.passwordalarmclock.MySpinner` вставляем ссылку на класс `MySpinner` (ПКМ по классу -> copy reference)

   ```
   <com.example.passwordalarmclock.MySpinner
       android:id="@+id/alarmRepeatingModeSpinner"
       android:layout_width="336dp"
       android:layout_height="75dp"
       />
   ```
3. Всё остальное оставляем как есть (всё стандартно), в том числе логику. В итоге просто `onItemSelected` начнёт срабатывать даже при повторном выборе.

Если кто знает решение, которое ещё проще, можете поделиться. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Я не знаю почему при вставке сайт не хочет форматировать класс как код - как не пытался форматировать, так и не получилось.

Comment: Из-за списка (1,2,3,...) нужно увеличивать отступ. ИМХО, лучше выделять блок кода тройным обратным апострофом ``` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting - так не нужно возиться с лишними пробелами